# How To Control The Depth Of DbContext.Update?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, relational-database

I want to control the depth of [`DbContext.Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-5.0). I'm afraid it would get stuck in an infinite loop or at the very least mark all the entities in the database as modified which would kill performance. I suspect it'll do that because my models are very interconnected. I'm looking for something with a similar effect to [`DbContext.Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-5.0) but with some way to limit the depth of the recursion.

I'm using a hosted blazor app so the database context must be able to detect changes made before it existed. I'm also using generated (scaffolded) code for the api controllers. I have one controller for each model and the relevent part is the PUT method, it currently uses `_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;` but that doesn't detect changes made to navigation properties. From what I read about [`DbContext.Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-5.0) it should detect those changes but I don't want to use it for the reason pointed out above.
My ultimate goal is to change the navigation properties of an entity and then call PUT for that change to be included in the database.

I thought about *'re-writing'* the code in [`DbContext.Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-5.0), but only for one iteration, taking advantage I know all the model types in advance. But I couldn't figure out how to detect deletion of relations, such as removal from a collection property or setting a reference property to `null`.

---

#### Additional Information

I've got 3 models: `Teacher`, `Class` and `Student`. Each teacher has sevral classes and each class has only one teacher (one-to-many). In addition, each class has sevral students and each student has sevral classes (many-to-many).

```cs
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Class> Classes { get; set; } = new List<Class>();
}

public class Class
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Student> Students { get; set; } = new List<Student>();
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Class> Classes { get; set; } = new List<Class>();
}

// Sample PUT method for the Student model where _context is the database context
// PUT: api/Students/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutStudent(int id, Student student)
{
    if (id != student.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    _context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!StudentExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return NoContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not complex at all. `_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified` does not detect the changes made on navigation properties because all entities in these navigation properties must be attached to the context and have their state set to `Modified` since they are untracked by the context currently. For example, if a Student has many Classes and you want to update them with the Student in PutSutdent method you have to do something like this.

```
foreach(var class in student.Classes) {
 _context.Entry(class).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

If you do not implement the above `foreach` statement for the student's classes all classes will be attached to the Context as `Unchanged` and no update to the database will be performed for them. More info on working with Entity state in different situations you can read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state

As I review your PutStudent method I think a better solution is to pass a custom DTO class object called StudentViewModel as the parameter, retrieve the real student entity from the database by Id, map the changes from the StudentViewModel properties to the Student (don't forget the navigation properties, for example, you may have to add/delete/update the classes related to that student) and save the changes to Student calling `_context.SaveChanges()` without setting the entity state explicitly. The update method can't cause an infinite loop if there are problems with the entity model regarding the database state a database exception will be thrown for example if you want to set a Class to an unexisting Teacher a foreign key exception will be thrown on calling `SaveChanges`. You can have more control over the relationships between the entity class in the `OnModelCreating` method of the `ApplicationDbContext` class. For example, you can set a foreign key relationship like this

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().HasMany(x => x.Classes).WithOne(x => x.Teacher)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

The above code means that when a Teacher is deleted all Classes related to that Teacher will also be deleted.

Comment: Your answer compromises of two suggestions: a simple `foreach` loop, and a more complex DTO. Regarding the first suggestion, how will I detect a deletion of a relation, e.g. calling `teacher.Classes.Remove(cls)` or `cls.Teacher = null`. Since the navigation properties won't be set to their previous value by the time the PUT method is called the only way I see of achieving this would be fetching the old value from the database and comparing the two, which leads me to the second suggestion.

Comment: Continuation: The easiest way I see to implement your second suggestion is to go field by field and mark the relevant fields as modified instead of modifying the old entity according to the new entity. Can I mark a navigation property as modified? I am unable to test your answer right now so I'm asking you instead in case you already know the answer, feel free to ignore these questions.